# NodeJS keep getting Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodejs-server

I'm trying to run a login project within nmp, I initialized the project, then the db side.
For now, when I try to run index.html and I get the mentioned above error. As well I'm not sure how to configure the "Run Configuration" of the project. Is anything wrong in my code? And where can I find more information on how to configure "Run Configuration" of the project accordingly.

```js
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require('path');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'Host',
    user     : 'root',
    password : '',
    database : 'nodeDB'
});



var app = express();
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended : true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.post('/auth', function(request, response) {
    var username = request.body.username;
    var password = request.body.password;
    if (username && password) {
        connection.query('SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = ? AND password = ?', [username, password], function(error, results, fields) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                request.session.loggedin = true;
                request.session.username = username;
                response.redirect('/home');
            } else {
                response.send('Incorrect Username and/or Password!');
            }
            response.end();
        });
    } else {
        response.send('Please enter Username and Password!');
        response.end();
    }
});

app.get('/home', function(request, response) {
    if (request.session.loggedin) {
        response.send('Welcome back, ' + request.session.username + '!');
    } else {
        response.send('Please login to view this page!');
    }
    response.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

```html
<script src="/index.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login Form Tutorial</title>
    <style>
        .login-form {
            width: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
        }
        .login-form h1 {
            text-align: center;
            color: #4d4d4d;
            font-size: 24px;
            padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        }
        .login-form input[type="password"],
        .login-form input[type="text"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        .login-form input[type="submit"] {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 15px;
            background-color: #535b63;
            border: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="login-form">
    <h1>Login Form</h1>
    <form action="auth" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: did you try node index,js ?

Comment: your works fine for me !!! it shows login page !!

Comment: How are you trying to access the page? Is it "http://localhost:3000/index.html"? This is not supposed to work, you can access normally on the / endpoint, like this: "http://localhost:3000/"

Comment: i think she is having issue with her IDE but otherwise her code is working fine !!! try to use Visual Studio Code for Node js it is easy to use

Comment: Thx @SaadSohail basically "node  index.js" worked fine now!

Comment: Thx @desoares "localhost:3000" works fine!

Comment: Basically this issue was solved by:
1) First in Terminal run "node index.js"
2) Opening "localhost:3000" in browser
3) And for "Run Configuration" I added in package.json the mentioned code.Then in "Run/Debug Configurations" I added npm, then in scripts label "start" and it works fine for me.

  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },

Answer (score 1):

you are missing script 'start' in `package.json` file.
If you add below code to your file it should run fine.

```
"scripts":{
  "start": "node app"
}
```

where app is your file name in which server is starting.